# Loop over values in an IEnumerable<> using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given an object possibly containing an `IEnumerable<T>`, how would I check that an `IEnumerable<T>` property exists, and if it does, loop over all values in that `IEnumerable<T>` using reflection, for any `T`?

Comment: "*possibly* containing an IEnumerable" ... what exactly are the other options besides IEnumerable then ?

Comment: what is a aim you want to achieve? Is all this types are your defined types?

Comment: @JaneDoe It can contain anything... string, int, IEnumerables, etc.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I didn't think the aim was important so I didn't mention it, but since it is... I want to take in any object and spit out a comma-separated list of all values, whether they be assigned to strings or ints or IEnumerables

Comment: @JaneDoe I don't want to... I want to only iterate over the IEnumerables

Comment: Let me know if my answer works correctly. I don't feel like setting up a reliable test case for it :P if it doesn't work, I'll fix it

Comment: Check my answer, it does not matter at all if its is IEanumerable or IEnumerable<T> (IEnumerable<T> implements IEnumerable) so, as long as you're not worried about T (and judging from the question you're not) that should work as expected.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
foreach (var property in yourObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
    {
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(yourObject, null))
        {
             //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost. Loose `<>` on IEnumerable, I think. It is the backwards compatible interface and is always there, IIRC. Note however, that using `var` there is just a synonym for `object`

Comment: thx a lot!  the only thing I had to change was `if (property.GetType()...` to `if (property.PropertyType....`

Comment: If you're using .net 4.5 the GetValue() is overloaded and does not require the null passed in.

Comment: Be aware that classes like `String` implement IEnumerable, so you might not always get the results you expect (unless you want a char array...)

Comment: @sehe `var item in (IEnumerable<>)propertyInfo.GetValue(model)` gives me "Unexpected use of an unbound generic name" and `var item in (IEnumerable)propertyInfo.GetValue(model)` gives me "using the generic type 'IEnumerable<T> requires 1 type arguments'"... Not sure what I am supposed to implement ?

Comment: If anyone is getting the error in my comment above, you need to include `System.Collections`, not just `System.Collections.Generic` like I was :) and then you can use `var item in (IEnumerable)propertyInfo.GetValue(model)`

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can test it as Aghilas said and, once tested and confirmed as IEnumerable you can do something like this:

```
public static bool IsEnumerable( object myProperty )
{
    if( typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(myProperty .GetType())
        || typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(myProperty .GetType()))
        return true;

    return false;
}

public static string Iterate( object myProperty )
{
    var ie = myProperty as IEnumerable;
    string s = string.Empty;
    if (ie != null)
    {
        bool first = true;
        foreach( var p in ie )
        {
            if( !first )
                s += ", ";
            s += p.ToString();
            first = false;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

foreach( var p in myObject.GetType().GetProperties() )
{
    var myProperty = p.GetValue( myObject );
    if( IsEnumerable( myProperty ) )
    {
        Iterate( myProperty );
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very nice that the person who just downvoted my answer explain why he/she did it instead of just downvote, it does not add anything valuable to the discussion otherwise.